# CRITICAL WORKER TIMEOUT when using eventlet and Firebase in Flask on gunicorn

Tags: firebase, flask, gunicorn, eventlet

I am developing a Flask application that uses WebSockets ( Flask-SocketsIO ) and Google Firebase. Theres a function which retrieves the user data from firebase, and sends notification to them. If I use `flask run` to start the web server, everything works fine, including Sockets and the notification method. But, when I use `gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 "app:create_app()""` for starting the web server, as soon as the notification sending method is called, the server kinda freezes, and in terminal, it shows following :
`[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT
exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7fb681db61d0 state=finished raised TypeError>`

The full error stack is shared [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nZDRZLMcAWlAeTyiF2ODi6d_f408a47M/view?usp=sharing)

Note that I can't use multiple workers since I am using Flask-SocketsIO. It doesn't supports multiple workers. Thanks!

Comment: Any answer? I am having the same issue.